# Android: Create spinner programmatically from array

Tags: android, spinner

I'm all new to Android and I'm trying to create a spinner programmatically and feeding it with data from an array, but Eclipse gives me a warning that I can't handle.

Here's what I got:

> This ArrayList holds the elements that should be in the spinner (gets
>   filled from a file later on):
>
> `ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();`

This is code I found on a site which should create the spinner:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Now the second line (ArrayAdapter...) gives me a warning in Eclipse saying `"ArrayAdapter is a raw type... References to generic type ArrayAdapter<T> should be parameterized"`, I have no idea how to fix this (or what that means in the first place :) ).

It's just a warning and the App seems to run alright, but I'd still like to understand what's wrong and fix it. Any hint is appreciated.

Greetings,
Select0r

Answer (score 402, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter<String>` should work.

i.e.:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
           spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
                                                     .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: I tried that but the error just changes slightly :)

`Type safety: The expression of type ArrayAdapter needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: Commented to quickly while you edited your post :) I missed the second `<String>`, your code works now, thanks a lot!

Comment: use `ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.simple_spinner_item); spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` or else a radio button may show up in the spinner on some devices.

Comment: your answere was helpful and can you please tell me that if i am using two spinners and i want if 1st spinner only then second should work

Comment: it also describes this method in the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 114):

In the same way with **Array**

```
// Array of choices
String colors[] = {"Red","Blue","White","Yellow","Black", "Green","Purple","Orange","Grey"};

// Selection of the spinner
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);

// Application of the Array to the Spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: I did this using an ArrayList because my array comes from a loop (not static).

Answer (score 68):

The following **3 lines of code** worked for me with a **string-array** named `shoes` loaded from the project resources:

```
Spinner              spinnerCountShoes = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_countshoes);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     this,
                     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
                     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shoes));
spinnerCountShoes.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);
```

This is my resource file (`res/values/arrays.xml`) with the **string-array** named `shoes`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="shoes">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>100</item>
        <item>1000</item>
        <item>10000</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

With this method it's very easy to make it multilingual, if necessary.

Comment: error: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: Seems you get an error trying out an answer I wrote almost 10 years ago. Maybe it's a good time to ask this question here on stackoverflow with your specific example.

Answer (score 36):

This actually worked for me

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
     
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner );
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this `Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);` when you do this `spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner );`

Comment: why 
error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous OnItemSelectedListener>,int,DetailData)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<String>) is not applicable ?

Answer (score 7):

this work for me:-

```
String[] array = {"A", "B", "C"};
String abc = "";


Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getContext());
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

I am using a Fragment.

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin language you can do it in this way:

```
val values = arrayOf(
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "chicken"
)

ArrayAdapter(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    values
).also {
    it.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    spinner.adapter = it
}
```