# How to use a personalized spinner with programatically created array of Strings instead of a hard-coded string array of my strings.xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

i have a personaliced spinner (that uses a adapter that uses a personalized xml layout file)

i want to pass him a array of strings, programatically created, instead of passing the tipical hard coded string array of strings.xml... but i can't!!   if i try to pass a array of strings, eclipse tell me that he needs a reference of a item from resources (a hard coded string array from strings.xml)

also i tryed to use the answer of this another way: [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)

but that way didn't work's for me, because that way must use the default layout `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and i won't work with that layout, i need to use my personalized layout (`R.layout.spinner_layout`), and that method didn't let me to use personalized layouts for the spinner

this is my code:

```
String[] teams=(String[])Primera.getTeams().toArray();

ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.teams_array, R.layout.spinner_layout);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
TeamsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
TeamsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

i need to changue `R.array.teams_array`, to `teams`, but i can't because the reason i told some lines up

can anyone help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use the `android.R.layout.spinner_item` etc. like what is being used in the question you reference. You can use your own layout xml for the spinner item.

You do not have to use `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()` you can use:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.id.your_custom_spinner_item, teams);
```

Comment: ..... spinner_item is my own custom_spinner_item...... i told in the question. And also i tryed to do without createFromResource and it fails, i told also in the question..... plz read before answer :(