# How to get spinner on android without xml

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my app I need a spinner on a `Button` click with dynamically loaded values. My need is in the XML file I should not use spinner control. **I have to show the spinner without xml on a button click:**

i use the following code but i did not get any error and spinner. i know i miss some lines. please Help me.

my code:

**showSpinner is a Button control.**

The **MyOnItemSelectedListene is outside of the onCreate(..)** method.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DynamicSpinnerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button b;
    LinearLayout linearLayout1;
    String years[] = new String[12];
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(DynamicSpinnerActivity.this, "sdfsdf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              Log.e("tag", "msg");
                Spinner spinnner = new Spinner(DynamicSpinnerActivity.this);
                int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    years[i] = Integer.toString(thisYear);
                    thisYear = thisYear + 1;
                }
                Log.e("tag", "msg"+years.length);
                ArrayAdapter<String> expYearAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DynamicSpinnerActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);
                expYearAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnner.setAdapter(expYearAdapter);
//              linearLayout1.addView(spinnner);
                spinnner.performClick();
                spinnner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

            }
        });
    }

    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Log.e("values", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be show using `spinnner.performClick();`

but @jitendra sharma ' way is better

Comment: thanks it show the spinner. How do i get selected text and position from the spinner.

Comment: look out the http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html for more info

Comment: spinnner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener()); is never called. please help me

Comment: hey Murali edited code is also working here, please paste the full activity code here so i can check you code

Comment: Is working setOnItemSelectedListener. do you add spinner in xml.

Comment: If you do not mine..can you send the project to murali6060@gmail.com ? please

Comment: have you seen my edited question there i past whole code. please correct my code.

Comment: yes i got the solution please remove comment from the  linearLayout1.addView(spinnner); line

Comment: and comment the performclick line you get the answer

Comment: yes but no. i get solution by using performclick and sharma way. But i add spinner control with width="0dp" and height ="0dp". with out xml. i did not get solution. Thanks for kind help

Answer (score 0):

you have created spinner its okay, but you also do need to add this layout to your contents on screen, like if you have llHolder to hold spinner, add spinner to

```
llHolder.addView(spinner);
```

Comment: can you explain this answer? what is llHolder.

Comment: yes thanks. it show the spinner. how to do i write listener for it?

Comment: spinnner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {..} is never called on when i select an item from the spinner.

Comment: the listener not called please help me

Comment: import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  
import android.widget.Spinner;  
i use those imports.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to display the spinner than default make it invisible and make it visible on button click