# Creating spinners dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Hi please suggest me a good example that shows how to create spinners dynamically (Like pressing a button add spinners)and retrieving values from them when submit.Am struck with my ideas..Help much appreciated

Comment: Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Example](http://www.lacherstorfer.at/haris_blog/2008/03/android-howto-create-spinners.html)  to create spinner dynamically. Please first googling and post question here.

Comment: IF You have solve these question then close your question by clicking the green tick, to close this question.Its next to the arrows at the top of this answer.