# Spinner based on entry field

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner, textedit

I am creating a spinner displaying numbers, but as the number could be up to 256 I don't want to have to have all entries 1-256 in my code. The number will be based on a entry field on a different class.

I.E if the user enters 16, the spinner will display number 1 to 16.

I am completely new to spinners so could some please talk in dummy terms if possible.

If this is not possible please help me with another solution.

Much appreciated.

Comment: spinners usually take adapters. adapters can take arrays. you can create an array that contains all values, dynamically. (loop on i, aray[i] = i or something)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)

Comment: @Abu Nope not a duplicate, nice spot anyway.

Comment: @ChrisJamesHancocks just thought it might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a way to add a `Spinner` programatically to your app.

Lets say you store your 16 items in an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Spinners can be created using `ArrayAdapters`

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

So far so good you've got a dynamic spinner but now you need data from it. Here's how you get it:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
          //Your logic for what happens when an Item is selected
        }
    });
```