# Supplying spinner with array, in xml or programatically?

Tags: android, android-spinner

When giving a String array to a spinner, is it better to do it in the xml or programitically?  My array has about 50 strings, and spinner will not change its array contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the spinner always show the same values, use XML. This will make it easier for you to manage the strings, and possibly add translations for them in a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change the contents of the array dynamically, a programmatic approach is the best option.

See a description of the programmatic approach [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)