# How to populate a Spinner from String array

Tags: android, string, spinner, android-arrayadapter

How can i populate a Spinner from `String array` , I know i can do that from `array.xml` like this `code` :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> gameKindArray = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(view.getContext(),R.array.game_kind, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        gameKindArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        gameKind.setAdapter(gameKindArray);
```

but when i have

```
String[] test=new String[]{"test1","test2"};
```

how i can change `String[]` to `ArrayAdapter` ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use ArrayAdapter this way

your string array

```
   String[] test=new String[]{"test1","test2"};
```

your ArrayAdapter

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> gameKindArray= new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivityClass.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
   gameKindArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   gameKind.setAdapter(gameKindArray);
```

Comment: I'm working with an integer array will this still work for that as well? if yes how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> gameKindArray =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);   
     gameKind.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For more info check the docs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to convert in any form just use your string array like below:

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> gameKindArray= new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivityClass.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
   gameKindArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   gameKind.setAdapter(gameKindArray);
```

you can get easily into spinner.