# Populating Android Spinner from MySQL Database

Tags: android, mysql, json, spinner

I'm trying to populate a `spinner` with values from a single field from my MySQL database (name of expense category), using php/JSON. Here's my code. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");

    $cat_query = "Select * from expense_categories" ;

    try {
                    $cat_stmt = $db ->prepare($cat_query);
                    $cat_result = $cat_stmt -> execute();
        }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
                    die(json_encode($response));
}   
    $cat_rows = $cat_stmt->fetchAll();

    if ($cat_rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($cat_rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();
        $post ["category_id"] = $row["category_id"];
        $post["Category_Name"] = $row["Category_Name"];

    //update our repsonse JSON data
    array_push($response["posts"], $post);
}

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);


} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
die(json_encode($response));
}
?>
```

When I run it it returns:

{"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","posts":[{"category_id":"1","Category_Name":"Travel"},{"category_id":"2","Category_Name":"Meals"}]}

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spincat"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="99dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
package;

imports;

public class Spinner_Category extends Activity {


private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.10.253:88/expenses/spinner_category.php";

private JSONArray jArray = null;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinner_category);

    }



public void updateJSON () {

    String POSTS = "posts";
    String ID = "category_id";
    String CATEGORY = "Category_Name";

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spincat);

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(LOGIN_URL);

    final String[] items = new String[jArray.length()]; 



    try{
        jArray = json.getJSONArray(POSTS);


        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //gets the content of each tag

            items[i]=c.getString(CATEGORY);
            items [i]=c.getString(ID);

        }        

    }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String> (Spinner_Category.this,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);  
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) ;


            spin.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items[i]=c.getString(CATEGORY);
items [i]=c.getString(ID);
```

seems a bit weird because you're overwriting the category placement with the id. is that on purpose? also if you log c.getString(CATEGORY) is it reading the json fine?

edit: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array) altho i think you've seen it