# Populating spinner with MySQL and JSON

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I am stuck because I don't know how to change populating `listView` to populate spinner.

The code below should work when in layout spinner is changed to `listview`, but I need spinner.

Can anyone explain to me how to do it?

In the Java file I'm using `DefaultHttpClient` method.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Spinner spinner;
private JSONArray jsonArray;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.spinner=(Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    new GetStat().execute(new Polaczenie());
}


public void setSpinner(JSONArray jsonArray){
    this.spinner.setAdapter(new GetAllTeamListViewAdapter(jsonArray,this));
    //this.GetStat.setAdapter(new GetAllTeamListViewAdapter(jsonArray,this));
}


public class GetStat extends AsyncTask<Polaczenie,Long,JSONArray>
{

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Polaczenie... params)
    {
        return params[0].GetStat();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {

        setSpinner(jsonArray);
    }

}
```

}

GetAllTeamListViewAdapter activity:

public class GetAllTeamListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private JSONArray dataArray;
private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


public GetAllTeamListViewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity a)
{
    this.dataArray=jsonArray;
    this.activity=a;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.dataArray.length();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListTeam team;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_team_list_view, null);
        team = new ListTeam();
        team.Name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team_full_name);
    }
    else
    {
        team =(ListTeam) convertView.getTag();
    }
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject=this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
        team.Name.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));

    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    return convertView;
}

private class ListTeam
{
    private TextView Name;


}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)