# Get android:text from online strings

Tags: java, android, string

How can i get android:text with online strings?

My code

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_contrnt"
android:text="@array/mylist"/>
```

I've tried

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_contrnt"
android:text="@http://myUrl.com/strings.xml"/>
```

Inside strings.xml in my server

```
<resources>
<string-array name="mylist">
<item>My Item1</item>
<item>My Item2</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

but it's fail

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't access online resources, as the [official site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) says:

> You should place each type of resource in a specific subdirectory of
>   your project's res/ directory. [...] the res/ directory contains all
>   the resources (in subdirectories).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,is there any  ways to update my string's data without updating the app? Because sometimes i'll change the dropdown list data

Comment: you could create an empty dropdown list, then read an online xml that contains all your items and add them dinamically, but I don't know if this could be good for your app performance since you have to read an online file

Comment: How about make a new button with text "Update App Data" to update the items?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
// Array of choices
String colors[] = {"Red","Blue","White","Yellow","Black","Green","Purple","Orange","Grey"};

// Selection of the spinner
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);

// Application of the Array to the Spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Find
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)

Comment: And how can i'm connect the string's data with my server data

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but your answer is not what i need right now

Comment: @AlfaRenaldoAluska This answer can help you. Just have a "getColors" method, where you then go online, check if colors is different, if it is, then download and replace colors. What is your server? and how are you encoding the output?

Comment: @Bonatti my file: http://alsk.pe.hu/strings.xml . I'm newbie with android programming.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access resources from the outside of the scope of the application.
[Start from here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) then, when you understand what is needed to gather the info, [use this instead, as its better.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

You need to have the following:

1 - The information you are seeking, for this answer I will suppose you have your own apache server with a PHP response method: "www.MyServer.com/getColors.php

2 - The class you are using the information

3 - Another class/service/asynctask to gather the info.

There are several ways for you to gather that data. If its likely that the data does not change much, I suggest checking the information when the app begins (the onCreate function) if the data changes a lot, I suggest doing it on the button onClick method instead.

Comment: Could you answer my others unanswered questions, please?