# Android Studio Spinner Causing App to Crash

Tags: android, android-spinner

This is doing my crust in!

I'm new to android app programming and my JAva in minimal to say the least. Obviously spending a lot of time searching around for how to do things.

I have a spinner in one of my layouts which I'm trying to populate from a string array.

I'm basing my work on this item:

[Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)

It doesn't matter what I do, every time it gets to the

```
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

line it causes the app to crash.

I declare the spinner and the array adapter like this:

```
Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter;
```

I've just noticed it says that spinnerArrayAdapter is never used despite it appearing the code below.

I even copied this code in directly to test it and it still crashes at that point: EDIT - Correct code from my app here rather than that from the example page.

```
    // Array of choices
    String colors[] = {"Red","Blue","White","Yellow","Black", "Green","Purple","Orange","Grey"};

    // Selection of the spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerArrays);

    // Application of the Array to the Spinner
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

I'm targeting Froyo as I want this to have maximum tolerance of the users' android version - although it is a limited appeal app specific to some hardware we have built.

Question is - why the heck does it keep bailing out when trying to populate the spinner.

If you need any more info, I'm afraid you'll have to spell out exactly where I get it from as I'm totally new to Android Studio!

This is all the red stuff from Logcat...

```
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.ictis.com.myarraydaya/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya.LiveStatus}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.ictis.com.myarraydaya.LiveStatus.onCreate(LiveStatus.java:39)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
10-10 12:55:10.596 18044-18044/app.ictis.com.myarraydaya E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My xml for the spinner is like this:

```
    android:id="@+id/spinnerArrays"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonCloseLive"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

EDIT: The full onCreate is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setupCloseButton();
    populateSpinner();
    // Application of the Array to the Spinner
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerArrays);

    // Array of choices
    String colors[] = {"Red","Blue","White","Yellow","Black", "Green","Purple","Orange","Grey"};

    // Selection of the spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerArrays);

    // Application of the Array to the Spinner
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);



   checkStatus();
}
```

If I comment out the

```
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Line, it works...

The populateSpinner() method doesn't actually do anything yet apart from println the contents of a dynamically created string array. CheckStatus() has no bearing on this either, and works fine. To test this I have  commented out both lines and it still crashes.

Comment: can you please your code from onCretae part as it clear from crash report there is some crash due to a array initialized there. Can you post your full code of that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing the problem is with the id of your spinner, in your code it's `R.id.myspinner` and in the xml it's `R.id.spinnerArrays`.

It should be the same, so try to change your code to `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerArrays);` in your code.

EDIT:

You also miss the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);` from your activity. 
This line is responsible for saying where to search for the veiws (for example your spinner) of your activity. It should be the second line after `super.onCreate()`!;

Comment: That was a typo on my part. In my app it was actually changed, but the code i posted was from the example. I've amended the code above.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. It was the missing setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout); that caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as stated below which was displayed in the Logcat section

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference**

This is because your id was misssing oncreate

I removed my spinner code from the onCreate method and pasted it in the  onCreateOptions Menu as below:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.partNumberRevisionSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
     R.array.wos, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    return true;
}
```

My array in string.xml array

```
  <string-array name="wos">
    <item>6021665</item>
    <item>6021666</item>
    <item>6021667</item>
    <item>6021668</item>
    <item>6021669</item>
    <item>6021671</item>
    <item>6021672</item>
    <item>6021673</item>
</string-array>
```

MY spinner in XML

```
   <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/partNumberRevisionSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

This worked for me now my spinner loads in my Navigation Drawer with no issues.