# How to set spinner value before that layout loads

Tags: android, layout, menu, spinner

I have a layout for menu options(like settings). I can't set the value for the spinner in my main Activity. How to do this in android. I am using eclipse

I can get the spinner by using following code  in onCreate method. but I can't set the values i didn't get any error

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MyExpensive.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chartconfiguration,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.chartConfig));
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.array.organizationTypes);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)

Answer (score 0):

Define the content of the Spinner by a String-Array in your strings.xml file:

```
  <string-array name="myspinnercontent">
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>C</item>
  </string-array>
```

And now create the adapter using `ArrayAdapter.creaFromResource` method:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> myAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.myspinnercontent, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```