# Spinner: Cannot Resolve Constructor

Tags: android

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"abc","abc"});

                // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // attaching data adapter to spinner
                spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array) and don't forget to do a little googling next time

Comment: getting error (Constructor cannot be resolve ) in dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
line

Comment: try [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably missing the context.

If you're using it in a fragment (Say AFragment.java), try;

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"abc","abc"});

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Or, if you're using it in an Activity (Say AActivity.java), try;

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"abc","abc"});

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```