# constructor cannot resolve Array adapter in android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I don't know what error I did. But it shows me `can not resolve constructor Arrayadapter` on my array adapter code.Help me to fix it out.( I have used getActivity() because I have written this code on my fragment section) and it gets crashes after it.I have tried almost all issue fixing methods in stack overflow .(Before down voting suggest me some solutions )

```
spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,def);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

[here is my error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJpiZ.png)

Comment: Remove getActivity() if you're on activity or remove this if you're on fragment... What is def?

Comment: remove getActivity() if you are using Activity. remove this if you are using fragment

Comment: def is the name of my array list and am doing in my fragment that's y i have added getActivity()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if you use a `fragment`:

**1. This code is designed to fetch a static array**

```
    ArrayAdapter myAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(), R.array.my_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

**2. If you are fetching a dynamic array, then the below sample code would work.**

In this sample, I've fetched the list from db. You can change upon your requirement.

```
    Spinner maritalSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.marital_spinner);
    List<MaritalStatus> maritalStatusList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> maritalStatusArray = new ArrayList<>();
    maritalStatusList = dbConnection.getMaritalStatus(maritalStatusDao);
    maritalStatusArray.clear();
    maritalIdArray.clear();
    maritalStatusArray.add("~Select~");
    maritalIdArray.add(0l); // this is number '0' and alphabet 'l'(small 'L') not number '1'
    for (MaritalStatus marital : maritalStatusList) {
        String maritalStatus = marital.getMaritalStat();
        long maritalId = marital.getMaritalId();
        maritalStatusArray.add(maritalStatus);
        maritalIdArray.add(maritalId);
    }
    maritalAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, maritalStatusArray);
    maritalAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    maritalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    maritalSpinner.setAdapter(maritalAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**your are passing to Context to your adapter so just pass one context**

> if your spinner in fragment than just change your adapter like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,def);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: this answer will be invalid if he is using fragment

Comment: @nilesh wait bro i ll try

Comment: My app crashes bro after using it

Comment: share your crash log @MilkaMozhi

Comment: 09-11 11:11:53.220: W/ErrorProcessor(2463): onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
09-11 11:11:53.220: W/ErrorProcessor(2463): com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
09-11 11:11:53.220: W/ErrorProcessor(2463):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)

Comment: **clean-rebuild-run** your project

Comment: 09-11 11:11:53.220: W/ErrorProcessor(2463):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
09-11 11:11:53.220: W/ErrorProcessor(2463):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
09-11 11:11:53.220: W/ErrorProcessor(2463):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-11 11:11:53.220: W/ErrorProcessor(2463):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)

Comment: @MilkaMozhi share your whole crash log with question edit in your question