# How to customize the spinner?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

I am creating a custom spinner with a custom background as that will hide the difficult dropdown, that's why I am setting a custom layout to show the dropdown. but when I am adding the adapter to the spinner the app is crashing? why?
This is the spinner code

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

This is drawable border

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:color="@color/text" android:width="1dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>

</shape>
```

this is the custom layout ---list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewDropdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewDropdown"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my fragment code

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val spinner=binding.spinner
        val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
            requireContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            this.listitem
        )//this is working fine
//        val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
//            requireContext(),
//            R.layout.list_item,
//            this.listitem
//        ) This is I wanted to do 
        spinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter
    }
```

The error I am getting

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView


Process: com.example.assignmentbackcoffer, PID: 32542
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

I don't wanted to change the border effect.
This is very important to me , I will be very happy if someone help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ID has to be a string.  Look like it is a number 5663.  So yo need to convert the number to a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" XML problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

Comment: Actually I don't know what is that number. on the array adapter I want to pass my custom layout but that is not working. 
I have updated my question a little can you please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to `ArrayAdapter` data type. It has only `String`, but you give him layout which contains text and image when it expects only string. Default `ArrayADapter` does not know how to process it. This code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array) should work:

```
Spinner              spinnerCountShoes = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_countshoes);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     this,
                     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
                     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shoes));
spinnerCountShoes.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);
```

Please [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android) for details on how to implement use case you asked.

Comment: Actually 
val spinnerAdapter=ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,this.listitem)

in this line after the context I want to provide my custom layout , and third arguments is just a array of string.  But when I am providing my custom layout instate of default android layout like  android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line this , the app is crashing with the mention error.

Comment: As I mentioned this Adapter requires layout with specific ids. To implement your own use case, you have to implement your custom ```Adapter```. More information about it including working example is under a second link in my post.